# Links are opening in a new tab/window by default from my web application

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window

All links are opening in a new tab/window from my web application.
I tested from Chrome and Firefox, same behavior for both.
I can't debug it. can anybody tell me the possible reasons and ways to debug it?

I am not using any target="blank" with the links, also I confirmed that no script is adding it to the DOM dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your **Ctrl** key is being pressed ?

Comment: No, For all other sites it is working normally

Comment: Can you share the URL or code which is causing issues ?

Comment: It was in my local. you can use this link: https://elegant-grain.usefinch.io

Comment: click on my cart on top and it will open a new browser window

Comment: It must be js, I am unable to trace the issue :(

Comment: hmm, I will look at the js then. Thank you for your help

Comment: Any solution found ?

Comment: I found a tool VisualEvent (https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) which shows the events occurring in a page, and found out some events are triggering while clicking on the body from a plugin (http://revolution.themepunch.com) I use. I am still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

Inside the head tag, I was written another tag like,

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

which defaults all links to open in target="_blank". If I say target="_self" the issue goes away.

Comment: This was the worst possibility one could think of. good luck!